# Al momento de pausar una lectura de pdf, el programa se rompe

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo una app que pase pdf a voz (en principio) pero tengo un problema que cuando abre el pdf al momento de leer todo bien, pero al momento de pausar se rompe el programa. No sabría dónde está el error; en un principio creo que es el for de la función *abrir* que se interrumpe al querer pausar.

```
import PyPDF2, pyttsx3

from tkinter import Button, Tk, Frame, filedialog, PhotoImage, Label, ttk, Text

from threading import Thread

import os

class LectorPDF(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        # Configuración de la ventana
        self.geometry('600x400+400+100')
        self.title('Leer PDF')
        self.config(bg='black')
        self.minsize(500, 300)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=8)
        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        
        # Definición del motor (?)
        self._engine = pyttsx3.init()
        self._reproduciendo = False
        
        # Imágenes
        self._image_file = PhotoImage(file= r'./archivo.png') 
        self._image_play = PhotoImage(file= r'./play.png')
        self._image_pause = PhotoImage(file= r'./pause.png')
        
        # Creación de frames y botones
        self._crear_frame()
        self._crear_botones()
    
    def _crear_frame(self):
        """
        Método que crea el frame principal (?)
        """
        # Frame Text
        self._frame_text = Frame(self, bg= 'white', width=400, height=400)
        self._frame_text.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='nsew', pady= 5, padx= 5)
        self._frame_text.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self._frame_text.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self._campo_texto = Text(self._frame_text, wrap='word')
        self._campo_texto.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsew')
        
        # Frame Control
        self._frame_control = Frame(self, bg= 'black', width=200, height=400)
        self._frame_control.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky='nsew', pady= 5, padx= 5)
        self._frame_text.grid_propagate(0)
        self._frame_control.grid_propagate(0)
        self._frame_control.columnconfigure([0,1], weight=1)
        self._frame_control.rowconfigure(list(range(9)), weight=1)
        
    def _crear_botones(self):
        """
        Método que crea los botones de control
        """
        # Botón Open
        self._button_open = Button(self._frame_control,image = self._image_file,compound= 'left',text= 'ABRIR ARCHIVO', font= ('Arial', 11, 'bold') , bg= 'blue', command= self._abrirArchivo)
        self._button_open.grid(columnspan=2, column=0, row=0, sticky='ew')
        # Botón Play
        self._button_play = Button(self._frame_control,image = self._image_play,compound= 'left',text= 'LEER', font= ('Arial', 11, 'bold') , bg= 'blue', command= self._cambiarPause)
        self._button_play.grid(columnspan=2, column=0, row=1, sticky='ew')
        
        # Label Velocidad 
        Label(self._frame_control, bg='black', fg='blue', text= 'VELOCIDAD', font=('Arial', 11, 'bold')).grid(columnspan=2, column=0, row=2)
        
        # Scale Velocidad
        self._scale_velocidad = ttk.Scale(self._frame_control,from_= 150, to= 350)
        self._scale_velocidad.grid(column=0, row=4, sticky='ew')
        # Signal Velocidad
        self._signal_velocidad = Label(self._frame_control, bg='black', fg='blue', text= '200', font=('Arial', 11, 'bold'))
        self._signal_velocidad.grid(column=1, row=4, sticky='ew')
        # Label Volumen 
        Label(self._frame_control, bg='black', fg='blue', text= 'VOLUMEN', font=('Arial', 11, 'bold')).grid(columnspan=2, column=0, row=5)
        # Scale Volumen
        self._scale_volumen = ttk.Scale(self._frame_control,from_= 0, to= 1)
        self._scale_volumen.grid(column=0, row=6, sticky='ew')
        
         # Signal Volumen
        self._signal_volumen = Label(self._frame_control, bg='black', fg='blue', text= '200', font=('Arial', 11, 'bold'))
        self._signal_volumen.grid(column=1, row=4, sticky='ew')
        
    def _abrirArchivo(self):
        """
        Método que muestra un diálogo de apertura de archivos PDF 
        """
        self._archivos = filedialog.askopenfilename(title= 'abrir', initialdir='C:/', filetypes=(('Archivos pdf', '*.pdf'),('todos los archivos', '*.*')))
        if self._archivos:
            with open(self._archivos, 'rb') as path:
                pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(path)
                self._q_pages = pdfReader.numPages
                for pages in range(self._q_pages):
                    self._text = pdfReader.getPage(pages).extractText()
            self.title(self._archivos)
            
    def _cambiarPause(self):
        """
        Metodo de cambio de iconos play/pause
        """
        if not self._reproduciendo:
            self._reproduciendo = True
            self._button_play ['image'] = self._image_play
            
            self._leer()
        else:
            self._reproduciendo = False
            self._button_play ['image'] = self._image_pause
            self._engine.endLoop()
        
    def _reproducir(self):
        """
        Método que reproduce el texto del PDF en español
        """
        if self._reproduciendo:  
            self._text          
            thread = Thread(target=self._leer, args=(self._text,), daemon=True)
            thread.start()
            self.poll_thread(thread)     
            
    def poll_thread(self, thread):
        if Thread.is_alive():
            self.after(100, lambda : self.poll_thread(thread))
        else:
            # self.next_page()
            pass
        
    def _leer(self):
        voices = self._engine.getProperty('voices')
        self._engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)
        self._engine.say(self._text)
        self._engine.startLoop() 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    app = LectorPDF()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Agrega más información, qué error te manda? cuál pausa?

Comment: La idea es que reduzcas el código a la minima porción necesaria para mostrar el error. Poner la aplicación completa desalienta las respuestas. Es decir, no creo que `signal_volumen` tenga que ver con el problema en cuestión

Comment: Intente ejecutar el código y falla el `__ini__()` en la librería `pyttsx3`. También faltan los `.png` de la UI.

Comment: holaa disculpa es la primera vez que publico y mande todo voy a reformular la pregunta poniendo de mejor manera el codigo